# Java Spring 2.19 Login Failed with custom authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-security

I am following a tutorial and when I try to login with "foo" as username and password using the form I get invalid username and password. Actually I don't see the need to enter the value "foo" but I am following the tutorial.

```
package com.dac.imoveis.controllers;

import com.dac.imoveis.controllers.MyUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;   


@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

     @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

UserDetailsService

```
 package com.dac.imoveis.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("foo", "foo", new ArrayList<>());
    }



}
```

The entry point class

```
     @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.dac.imoveis.controllers"})
public class ImoveisApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImoveisApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I am following a tutorial"* Which tutorial would that be? Because I'm pretty certain that your `SecurityConfigurer` class is missing the `@Configuration` annotation, and without it, the class is ignored by the Spring framework. If the tutorial you're using is also missing the annotation, then you should stop following that *flawed* tutorial. Otherwise, if you follow a tutorial, make sure you follow it correctly.

Comment: this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE

Comment: I added @Configuration but the same results.

Comment: Since we can't see the rest of your code, we can only wonder what else you got wrong, to make it not work.

Comment: I will add more code.

Comment: I added the imports and packages and the entry point class. I think that's all the relevant code.

Comment: It's kind of weird to have a `@Service` in a `controllers` package. Anyway, seems `SecurityConfigurer` still doesn't have `@Configuration`. What is the package of the `ImoveisApplication` class? Also, try removing `@ComponentScan` and specify `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.dac.imoveis.controllers"})`

Comment: ImoveisApplication is in the package "com.dac.imoveis".

Comment: Don't explain in comments. Edit the question and add the information there.